# "Content-Range" response header not visible for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, httpresponse

I have the following code:

```js
const URL = 'https://www.tophtml.com/snl/15.mp3';
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
 const button_load  = document.querySelector('.button_load');
 button_load.addEventListener('click', async function() {
  let url = URL + '?nocache='+(new Date()).getTime();
  let arrayBuffer = await fetchData(url, 501, 510);
  console.log('This is the response itself:');
  console.log(arrayBuffer);
 });
});
function fetchData(url, byte_from, byte_to) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.setRequestHeader("Range", "bytes=" + byte_from + "-" + byte_to);
  request.onload = function() {
   resolve(request.response);
  }
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == this.HEADERS_RECEIVED) {
    console.log('These are the "Response Headers" visible to JavaScript:');
    console.log(request.getAllResponseHeaders());
   }
  }  
  request.send();
 });
}
```

```html
<button class="button_load">Load</button>
```

which you can also find here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OBJqZG?editors=1010

My problem is that for some reason, the `Content-Range` response header is not visible for `JavaScript` as you can see on the following image:

[image]

Any idea of what's going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any idea of what's going on here?

It's quite simple, `content-range` is a **response** header and *not* a request header. The only response header that can be set—using `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.overrideMimeType`—from the client side is the `content-type`.

**If it is exposed** by the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` response header you may retrieve it using:

```
request.getResponseHeader('Content-Range')
```

Comment: but is there any way I can get the value of: `Content-Range` by using `JavaScript` once I submit the request?, any workaround or something?. Thanks!

Comment: could you please fork my `CodePen.io` and alert the value? thanks!

Comment: @davidesp check my update. It's not possible in that case: it's not exposed. Try it out and look at your console.